# QGIS Fieldcalculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgsexpression

I have a QGIS layer with points and the column 'name'. This column contains names like "AS 10450 to 1045" or "BAS 1045B100 to AS 1457745".
Now I want to create another column with all values from 'name' but only the part of the string after the 'to', the 'to' should included in the new column.
Some rows does not contain the string 'to', they have values like "AS10" or "SAB145500 14552AS".

I tried the fieldcalculator with different expressions:

```
"name" LIKE '%to%'
```

==> I only get the count of the value 'to'

```
substr("name","name" like '%to%')
```

==> All values were filled in the new column

```
regexp_substr("name",'to')
```

==> I only get the value 'to' in the new column

Where is my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substr("name",regexp_match("name",'to')+3)` should work.

`regexp_match` searches column `name` for the string `to` and returns the place where this string begins.

`substr` returns a part of the column `name` beginning at a place in this string. In this case this is where `to` starts plus three in order to account for the length of the word `to` and the following space.

Comment: Then edit your question so it contains all possible variations @joe_gerner.

Comment: It works fine, thank you very much